# Using a Hot Wheels Radar Gun with FreqPeriod library

Tags: frequency, adc

I want to make a clone of those radar enforcement signs that look like this:
[image]

I bought a Hot Wheels Radar gun that can send an analog signal to determine speed.  See this thread:  http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=145063.msg1889312#msg1889312

From FreqPeriod's documentation, it has the following comment in the code:

`connect pin 5,6,7 to input circuit`

Question is -- how do I wire up the radar gun analog signal wire to the arduino to successfully use FreqPeriod?

Comment: What makes you think that the FreqPeriod library has anything whatsoever to do with this...?!  5 seconds reading that thread and the link to the project within it and I already know that FreqPeriod is NOT what you want to be using. Go do some more reading.

Comment: The post below the one I linked to included a working sketch, rigged up the the guts of the hot wheels radar gun. There are a few in the forums that have used that sketch to get speed using FreqPeriod.  I just need help figuring out how to wire it up.

Comment: Ignore the forum, most of that is talking gibberish. Instead read the project page. The code linked to by the forum thread is for something entirely different. For the hotwheels it gives an analog signal that you just read with analogRead(). FreqPeriod is used if you are building your own doppler circuit and doing the work in the Atmel. The hotwheels one does the work in external hardware and just gives you an analog voltage. Or that's what the project page says.